# How to clear contents of ng-view

Tags: angularjs, ng-view

In my web page, I have left panel inside that there is tree control.when I select a node in tree control am loading respective details in right side ng-view.

But currently what happens is if I select a second node, details are getting appended in the right side ng-view.

what I need is when I select a node in tree, need to clear the ng-view and load the data.

How to achieve this ?

```
    <div class="row height100">

        <!--splitter starts-->
        <div class="col-lg-12 col-md-12 col-sm-12 height100" ng-controller="SplitterController as vm">
            <!--Menu container strts-->
            <div id="splitter" class="splitterHeight height100" kendo-splitter k-options="vm.splitterOptions">
                <div class="leftContainer col-lg-3 col-md-3 col-sm-3 col-xs-12 height100">
                    <div id="divTreeContainerWrapper" class="height100 width100">
                        <!-- Tree control inside -->
                    </div>
                </div>
                <!--Menu container ends-->
                <!--Content container strts-->
                <div class="col-lg-9 col-md-9 col-sm-9 col-xs-12 rightContainer height100">
                    <div class="topIconCotainer">
                        <div class="row pull-right">
                            <!--<ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">-->
                            <a href="#/Summary">Summary</a>
                            <a href="#/add">Add</a>

                            <!--</ul>-->

                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="bottomContentContainer">


                        <div ng-view></div>

                    </div>
                    <!--Content container ends-->
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>

        <!--splitter ends-->
    </div>

</div>
```

Comment: Some code will be helpful here

Comment: @AlonEitan I am trying to clear the ng-view, Is there any way for that. Beacuse for this scenario  I have to put 7 files of code.

Comment: Just the layout template would be useful

Comment: have you tried routing?

Comment: @StianStandahl I can do that, but problem is for complete right side content I have a single controller, so my html will be reloaded and again controller instance creation will happen, so it will be overhead when ever I select the node. When node is selected , from left side an event is emitted and subscribed in the right side controller

Comment: @MuliYulzary added layout code

Comment: Why don't you hide the right-side content before loading the data, then after your loading is complete you show it again (When clicking a node) with ng-hide/ng-show?

Comment: @MuliYulzary i can do that, but i need to clear the content, now content is getting appended. Let say i selected node1, node1 details loaded. Now node2 is selected, it contains both node1 data and  node2 data.

Comment: Could you show your nodes templates?

Comment: which version of angular are you using? I once tried to have a ng-view inside a controller. But, that can be difficult in version 1.x. I dont know if they have done anything to solve the problem with having nesten views, but I know i had to restructure the app to work around it.

Comment: Am using Angular 1.5